# iOS how fill a shape with color

Tags: ios, colors, png, fill

I have seen this solution a couple a year ago, but not able to find it now. My question is:

I have a PNG with a flower. the background is white or transparent and the flower is painted in black outlines. I want to touch a white/transparent area and fill it with a color.

Hopefully someone remember the solution and can help me to find it, many thanks

Comment: you can just change the background color on touch, no?! or you want to fill the actual flower with color? if you want the flower to be painted, just make another PNG with painted one, and replace on touch

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking... sounds a lot like the [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) though.

Comment: It is the first part you mention, fill the black borders with a color. And yes, could be the flood fill algorithm, but in Objective-C

Comment: @DietMarSchwarzWebers for some reason cocoapods does not respond for me. But I remember that I have seen there a pod which used the flood fill algorithm. I found it by writing "Paint" in the search field

Comment: I got it: https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill, was what I am looking for. I will give it a try. But looks like what I was looking for.